# jQuery .load with select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using JQuery .load to open other pages into a modal

```
function LoadModal(page, title) {
    title = title || '';

    $( "#modal_page" ).fadeIn("slow");
    $( "#modal_title" ).html(title);

    $("#modal_page_body").html('<h2 align="center">Loading...</h3><p align="center"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-5x"></i></p>');
    $("#modal_page_body").load(page, function(){

    });
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
}
```

and i call it here:

```
<a href="#" onClick="LoadModal('/section/helpdesk/newticket', 'New Ticket');" title="New Ticket"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i></a>
```

I am using the select2 library (select2.github.io) which works okay on my main pages (index.php etc) but its not working on the popup modal divs (when using JQuery .load)

other JQuery functions are working okay, like `.autocomplete` - that works fine

Comment: Try with full path `baseUrl + section/helpdesk/newticket`

Comment: inside the '' or outside? baseurl + '' or 'baseurl + '

Comment: or shall i add into the function .load(baseurl + page)

Comment: use full url to `load`.

Comment: `onClick="LoadModal('baseUrl + /section/helpdesk/newticket', 'New Ticket');"`

Comment: Where is your code to apply `select2`? That will not automatically apply to dynamically loaded content.

Comment: its in my index.php page, and that works fine. i have set all select elements to init the select2. so its working fine but just not on pages when using .load

Comment: @ParthTrivedi using the baseUrl stops the .load from working

Comment: what have you change?

Comment: what you said in your comment

Comment: Of course it works in your index.php.. that is not Ajax loaded!! select2 is not designed to have delegated behaviour. It must be attached to each select individually. Please supply the code you use to init select2, or an example of your loaded page's HTML. @BG101 has implemented a variation of what I would suggest anyway below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the `complete` callback of `load` you will need to call the `select2` initializer. it will not automatically get called on dynamic content:-

```
$("#modal_page_body").load(page, function(){
    $('#new_select').select2();
});
```